# when i submit the data, it is not shown in table and show error. after refreshing it shown correctly

Tags: php

I want to assign the value from database

HTML

```
<?php

$dbhost = 'localhost:3306';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'root';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db("test_db", $conn);



if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
if(!empty($_FILES))
  {
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png","txt");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["resume"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if (($_FILES["resume"]["size"] < 50000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["resume"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["resume"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["resume"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["resume"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["resume"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"];
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file\n";
  }

$name = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$quali = $_POST['quali'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];
$resume = $_FILES["resume"]["name"];



$sql = "INSERT INTO form ".
       "(name,age,quali,state,country,msg,resume) ".
       "VALUES('$name','$age', '$quali', '$state','$country','$msg','$resume')";

mysql_select_db('test_db');

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo "Entered data successfully\n";

move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"], "files/".$_FILES["resume"]["name"]);
}

mysql_close($conn);

}
?>
<div>
    <form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div>Name:<input type="text" name="name" /></div>
        <div style="height:10px"></div>
        <div>Age:<input type="text" name="age" /></div>
        <div style="height:10px"></div>
        <div>Qualification:<input type="text" name="quali" /></div>
        <div style="height:10px"></div>
        <div>State:
        <select name="state">
          <option value="tn">TamilNadu</option>
          <option value="kl">Kerala</option>
          <option value="ka">Karnataka</option>
          <option value="ani">Andhara</option>
        </select>
</div>
        <div style="height:10px"></div>
        <div>Country:<input type="text" name="country" /></div>
        <div style="height:10px"></div>
        <div>Resume:<input type="file" name="resume" /></div>
        <div style="height:10px"></div>
        <div>Message:<textarea cols="10" rows="5" name="msg"></textarea></div>
        <div style="height:10px"></div>
        <div><input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
    </form>
</div>
<div style="height:30px"></div>

<div>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Qualification</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Resume</th>
        <th>Message</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM form";
$retval1 = mysql_query($sql1,$conn);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval1))
{
$name_s = $row['name'];
$age_s = $row['age'];
$quali_s = $row['quali'];
$state_s = $row['state'];
$country_s = $row['country'];
$resume_s = $row['resume'];
$msg_s = $row['msg'];
?>
<tr>
    <td><label name="name_s"><?php echo $name_s; ?></label></td>
    <td><label name="age_s"><?php echo $age_s; ?></label></td>
    <td><label name="quali_s"><?php echo $quali_s; ?></label></td>
    <td><label name="state_s"><?php echo $state_s; ?></label></td>
    <td><label name="country_s"><?php echo $country_s; ?></label></td>
    <td><label name="resume_s"><?php echo $resume_s; ?></label></td>
    <td><label name="msg_s"><?php echo $msg_s; ?></label></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
</div>
```

when i submit the data, it is not shown in table and show error. after refreshing it shown correctly

It is my testing program only not for any application. tell me some suggestion. do i use ajax for that? or any other.

Comment: Try `<label name="<?php echo $name_s; ?>"></label>` if that's what you mean to do.

Comment: It returns  Notice: Undefined variable: name_s in C:\xampp\htdocs\Deen_php\form.php on line 57
">

Comment: Is your HTML above or below PHP?

Comment: My html is below the php..  $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM form";
$retval1 = mysql_query($sql1);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval1))
{
$name_s= $row['name'];
$name_s = htmlspecialchars($row['name_s'],ENT_QUOTES);
echo $name_s;
}  <td><label name="name_s"><?= $name_s ?></label></td>

Comment: And this doesn't work? `<label name="name_s"><?php echo $name_s; ?></label>`

Comment: Did you try the other answer given below? Although he/she made a mistake in mixing `mysqli_*` with `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: If your DB connection is `mysqli_` then change `$retval1 = mysql_query($sql1);` to `$retval1 = mysqli_query($sql1);`

Comment: I have given correctly mysql which i was used. but it doesn't show the datas

Comment: I also need to see what your DB setup is, replacing credentials with `xxx` - I posted an answer below, based on `$con` being the DB variable for DB connections.

Comment: In the future, post your full code so that we/I won't be guessing what you have for code. I deleted my answer by the way.

Answer (score 5):

**Using mysqli_connect**

```
<?php
  $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","your_database") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connect));
  $query = "SELECT * FROM form" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($connect));
  $result = $connect->query($query);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

  ?>
 <tr>
        <td><label name="name_s"><?php echo $row['name_s']; ?></label></td>
        <td><label name="age_s"><?php echo $row['age_s']; ?></label></td>
        <td><label name="quali_s"><?php echo $row['quali_s']; ?></label></td>
        <td><label name="state_s"><?php echo $row['state_s']; ?></label></td>
        <td><label name="resume_s"><?php echo $row['resume_s']; ?></label></td>
        <td><label name="msg_s"><?php echo $row['msg_s']; ?></label></td>
    </tr>
} 
?>
```

**Using mysql_connect**

```
 <?php
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
    mysql_select_db("your_database", $connect);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM form";
    $retval = mysql_query($sql, $connect);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval))
    { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><label name="name_s"><?php echo $row['name_s']; ?></label></td>
        <td><label name="age_s"><?php echo $row['age_s']; ?></label></td>
        <td><label name="quali_s"><?php echo $row['quali_s']; ?></label></td>
        <td><label name="state_s"><?php echo $row['state_s']; ?></label></td>
        <td><label name="resume_s"><?php echo $row['resume_s']; ?></label></td>
        <td><label name="msg_s"><?php echo $row['msg_s']; ?></label></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks to all. It work correctly , i made small mistake in that. i didn't select the database. Now i got it.

Comment: @Mohaideen Welcome! For you knowledge i provided query with MySQL and MySQLi.

Comment: Mohaideen, please take into consideration switching to mysqli while you can.

Answer (score 0):

You should then be able to access your '$name_s' variable, and place it into your table like:

```
<td><label name="name_s"><?= $name_s ?></label></td>
```

Where the `<?= $name_s ?>` is a shortcut to output the variable's value outputting the value inside the label element.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM form";
$retval1 = mysql_query($sql1);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval1))
{
$name_s = $row['name_s'];
$age_s = $row['age_s'];
$quali_s = $row['quali_s'];
$state_s = $row['state_s'];
$resume_s = $row['resume_s'];
$msg_s = $row['msg_s'];
?>
<tr>
    <td><label name="name_s"><?php echo $name_s; ?></label></td>
    <td><label name="age_s"><?php echo $age_s; ?></label></td>
    <td><label name="quali_s"><?php echo $quali_s; ?></label></td>
    <td><label name="state_s"><?php echo $state_s; ?></label></td>
    <td><label name="resume_s"><?php echo $resume_s; ?></label></td>
    <td><label name="msg_s"><?php echo $msg_s; ?></label></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: You're mixing `mysqli_*` with `mysql_*` functions, fix that. OP is using `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: It gives warning and data doesn;t show.. error is  Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Deen_php\form.php

Comment: See my comment above --^ @Mohaideen change `mysqli_fetch_array` to `mysql_fetch_array` - The person did not bother fixing the major error in mixing both types of functions.

Comment: Oh wait a minute, that's your mistake. @Mohaideen You can't mix both types of functions. Need to know what your DB settins are, if `mysqli_` or `mysql_`

Comment: Same warning appear  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Deen_php\form.php